# Help with Java Arrays: Saving to output file

Tags: java, arrays, file

```
public char[] calculateGrade(int [] scores, char [] grades){
    for (int r = 0; r < scores.length; r++){
        //System.out.println(scores[r] + " ");
        if (scores[r] > 90)
            grades[r] = 'A';
        else if (scores[r] > 80)
            grades[r] = 'B';
        else if (scores[r] > 70)
            grades[r] = 'C';
        else if (scores[r] > 60)
            grades[r] = 'D';
        else
            grades[r] = 'F';
    for (int i = 0; i < grades.length; i++)
        System.out.println(grades[i]);

    }
    return grades;

}
```

Above is a small part of my overall program that takes scores from a file and turns them into letter grades.  I need to put these letter grades into that file.  The letter grade needs to correspond with the score.  There are 26 different scores one line at a time.  I would put my entire code in here but it is really long. Please help guys!

Comment: The last for loop only prints all the grades multiple times.  I am really confused...

Comment: By the way, I realize nobody else mentioned the problem with your code. Your loops are nested. So every time you read a score, you print all grades. Be careful with the brackets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend having each method do one thing and do it well.  Don't calculate grades and print them out.

```
public void printGrades(PrintStream ps, char [] grades) {
    for (char grade : grades) {
       ps.println(grade);
    }
}

public char[] calculateGrade(int [] scores){

    char [] grades = new char[scores.length];

    for (int r = 0; r < scores.length; r++){
        if (scores[r] > 90)
            grades[r] = 'A';
        else if (scores[r] > 80)
            grades[r] = 'B';
        else if (scores[r] > 70)
            grades[r] = 'C';
        else if (scores[r] > 60)
            grades[r] = 'D';
        else
            grades[r] = 'F';
    }
    return grades;

}
```

Comment: and I suppose, he only reads the scores from the file. So, "char [] grades" as a parameter of calculateGrade() is also a wrong approach.

Comment: I dont understand, you obviously are creating the grades array in the method and returning it to the class but how does the class understand it.  Isnt it a local variable?

Comment: I took the "char [] grades" out of the parameter list after realizing that the cut & paste solution was not preferred.

Comment: So instead of printing the grades, how would I assign them to a file?  Lets say there are 20 lines of someones name and their score, I need to put the letter grade after that score. How would I go about doing this?  Sorry for the noobness...

Comment: You don't "assign" them to a file.  You write to a file after opening it.  Modify the method I gave you to include an array of names, scores and grades.  Or, better yet, a List<Grade> or some other class that encapsulates name, score, and grade into a single unified thing.  Java's an object-oriented language.

Comment: Thank you I will definately be fiddling with this all night

Answer (score 1):

Change your method to just the following:

```
public void calculateGrade(int[] scores, char[] grades){
    for (int r = 0; r < scores.length; r++) {
        if (scores[r] > 90)
            grades[r] = 'A';
        else if (scores[r] > 80)
            grades[r] = 'B';
        else if (scores[r] > 70)
            grades[r] = 'C';
        else if (scores[r] > 60)
            grades[r] = 'D';
        else
            grades[r] = 'F';
    }
}
```

There's no need to return `grades` since arrays are passed by reference anyways. Then in your calling method (`main`?), you should write `grades` to the file you want.

To write to a file, consult: http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.io/WriteToFile.html

So something like:

```
try {
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("filename")));

    for( char grade : grades )
        out.println(grade);

    out.close();
} catch (IOException e) { }
```

Comment: Thanks man but the last part is a little too complicated lol. I am a junior CS student and I haven't learned about those keywords so far.  So I need to keep it simple haha.  But I understand the first part!

Comment: That's just how you write to a file. Don't worry about the `try` or the `catch`. Just think of `out.println` as similar to `System.out.println` except writing to a file.